# Finding the order of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

For the solution in part (b), I am confused about how they got that $(0,1)$ has order $2$. For the others, such as say $(2,1)$, isn't is just lcm$(|2|,|1|)=2$ for the order? I'm confused about how this works.

Comment: $(0,1)+(0,1) = (0,2) = (0,0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(0,1)$ has order $2$ in $\mathbb Z_4\oplus\mathbb Z_2$, because $(0,1)\ne(0,0)$ but $(0,1)+(0,1)=(0,2)=(0,0)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you.